# xamarin.forms maps hide zoom buttons (+-)

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

I want to hide the +- zoom buttons in xamarin.forms but keep the zooming capability

The property HasZoomEnabled removes the buttons but also disable the zooming capability

is there any solution without rendering ?

if not i will be happy to get a solution with rendering in android

Comment: Would be nice if someone answered this for the xamarin forms case.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this

Answer (score 11):

Create your custom control using a custom renderer

So in your pcl project add

```
public class CustomMap : Map
    {
        public CustomMap(MapSpan region) : base(region)
        {
        }
    }
```

In your android project add

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]

namespace MobApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);                

            var map = ((MapView)Control).Map;
            map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
            map.UiSettings.MyLocationButtonEnabled = false;
            map.UiSettings.RotateGesturesEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
var map = new CustomMap(
                MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                    new Position(37.990599, 23.766820), Distance.FromKilometers(1)))

            {
                IsShowingUser = true,
                HeightRequest = 100,
                WidthRequest = 960,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
```

Comment: It works at time i still in this project. Sorry Xamarin have been updates a lot times. can't guarantee now.

Comment: I also want the same feature in my app, but i got an error in var map = ((MapView)Control).Map;

Comment: @AswathyKR I found the solution : use NativeMap.UiSettings instead

Answer (score 6):

Some things have may changed since 2016, so here is an up to date solution for this (At 2020/Jan):

You will need to Create a CustomRenderer as mentioned in the comments, and override the following method "OnMapReady" like this:

```
    protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        base.OnMapReady(map);
        map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
        map.UiSettings.MyLocationButtonEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Can we able to add these zoom control buttons in ios

Comment: @Deepakkumar I think you need to implement it by your own

Comment: Thank you for your response. IOS we have any predefined controls for zoom in and zoom out like android we have predefined controls.